# ngOptions setting value attribute of option to unexpected values

Tags: angularjs

I have some doubts with using ngoptions. I am not able to set value attribute for the option items.Here is [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUjOCGSl5sBM8VWVef7F?p=preview)

```
  $scope.ListOfValues=[{optiontext:'Active',optionvalue:'opt1'},
     {optiontext:'inactive',optionvalue:'opt2'},
     {optiontext:'terminated',optionvalue:'opt3'}];
```

And my html code is

```
 <select id="emptype" ng-model="empstatus" ng-options="emp.optionvalue as emp.optiontext  for emp in ListOfValues">
</select>
```

The generated html is as shown below.

```
<select id="emptype" ng-model="empstatus" ng-options="emp.optionvalue as emp.optiontext  for emp in ListOfValues" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">
  <option value="string:opt1" label="Active">Active</option>
  <option value="string:opt2" label="inactive">inactive</option>
  <option value="string:opt3" label="terminated">terminated</option>
</select>
```

I was expecting it to be as shown below

```
<select id="emptype" ng-model="empstatus" ng-options="emp.optionvalue as emp.optiontext  for emp in ListOfValues" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">
      <option value="opt1" label="Active">Active</option>
      <option value="opt2" label="inactive">inactive</option>
      <option value="opt3" label="terminated">terminated</option>
 </select>
```

So why does it add string: to the value attribute? How i can get my desired output?

Comment: AngularJS just seems to use this internally. I wouldn't worry about what the rendered HTML actually is. If you bind `{{empstatus}}` you will see that it will be `opt1` rather than `string:opt1` anyway.

Comment: yes . ng-model will update with the optionvalue . But i wanted to render html elements in same way.any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

It has to deal with 1.3 -> 1.4 Angular version API change - if you check this [plunkr (v.1.3)](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUjOCGSl5sBM8VWVef7F?p=preview) it will show just indexes as values of the `<option>` tags.

To make it also work with Angular +1.4 you should add the following statement to your ng-options expression `track by emp.optionvalue`. See this [plunkr (v.1.4)](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUjOCGSl5sBM8VWVef7F?p=preview) .

```
 <select id="emptype"
         ng-model="empstatus"
         ng-options="emp.optionvalue as emp.optiontext for emp in ListOfValues track by emp.optionvalue">
     </select>
```

But the value of the `ng-model` is correctly updated in both cases, see `{{empstatus}}` in template of my examples.
So as @ExplosionPills say that should not be a issue.

Comment: Nice. But the plunker that you shared as v 1.3 works if you add track by. So is it version specific?